# Retireving data from arrays

Tags: cakephp

I have this data spited out from my cake php query.. This is the problem.. How can i retrieve this data so that it fits this structure. How can I do this in my view?, I am just having trouble understanding how to retrieve each value

so this part I want it in a `<p></p>` in my page

```
array
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'category_name' => string 'Appetizers' (length=10)
  'category_keywords' => string 'appetizer, appetizers' (length=21)
  'category_title' => string 'Our Side Dishes' (length=15)
  'category_info' => string 'Hello This is the category info' (length=30)
  'dish_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

This other part returned of the query i want to put it in a 3 x 2 table. like

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td> the data from the array 0</td>
 <td> the data from the array 1</td>
 <td> the data from the array 2>/td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> the data from the array 3</td>
 <td> the data from the array 4</td>
 <td> the data from the array 5>/td>
</tr>
```

here are all the those arrays. I would like to use a for loop with a mod if 3 %== 0 and then create a new `<tr>`, i tried it but it gave me an error...

```
 array
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'category_name' => string 'Appetizers' (length=10)
  'category_keywords' => string 'appetizer, appetizers' (length=21)
  'category_title' => string 'Our Side Dishes' (length=15)
  'category_info' => string 'Hello This is the category info' (length=441)
  'dish_id' => string '1' (length=1)

array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'dish_name' => string 'Arepa Con Pollo!' (length=16)
      'dish_disc' => string 'Exquisite corn patti, the best yyy' (length=34)
      'dish_price' => string '2.90' (length=4)
      'dish_image' => string '/img/arepa rellena con pollo.jpeg' (length=33)
      'dish_category_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'dish_price_label' => string 'Delicious Arepa ' (length=16)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'dish_name' => string 'Arepa Con Queso' (length=15)
      'dish_disc' => string 'Corn patie with Cheese' (length=22)
      'dish_price' => string '2.65' (length=4)
      'dish_image' => string '/img/arepa rellena con queso.jpeg' (length=33)
      'dish_category_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'dish_price_label' => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'dish_name' => string 'Empanadas de Carne' (length=18)
      'dish_disc' => string 'Patties with beef' (length=17)
      'dish_price' => string '1.60' (length=4)
      'dish_image' => string '/img/empanadas de carne.jpeg' (length=28)
      'dish_category_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'dish_price_label' => string '' (length=0)
  3 => 
    array
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'dish_name' => string 'Empanadas de Pollo' (length=18)
      'dish_disc' => string 'Patties with Chicken' (length=20)
      'dish_price' => string '1.94' (length=4)
      'dish_image' => string '/img/empanadas de pollo.jpeg' (length=28)
      'dish_category_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

There are more arrays besides these.. but they all have the same format.

These come from working with the following controllers

```
class DishCategory extends AppModel{

           public $hasMany = array(
            'Dish' => array(
                'className' => 'Dish',
                'foreignKey' => 'dish_category_id'
            )
        );

 }

class DishCategoriesController extends AppController {

 function get_categories($id)
      { 
        // find category with a dish of $id
        $this->set('dishes', $this->DishCategory->find('first', array(
          'conditions' => array(
            'DishCategory.id' => $id
          )
        )));

        // set master layout
        $this->layout = 'master_layout';
      }     
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this->set('variableName', $data);` to pass your arrays from the controller to the view.

You can then access the example above as `$variableName` in your view. I would recommend doing a `<?php debug($variableName); ?>` first to see what your array looks like in the view. It should be the same, but it will help you know what indices to use.

For more info: http://book.cakephp.org/view/979/set

Comment: Thats my problem i am not sure how to retrieve it in the view... I already have the data showing as i posted above

Comment: What's the problem? Once you have your arrays in the view, use a for or a foreach to iterate through each and print the specific data you need in html tags. The baked index.ctp file for any database table is a good example of this.

Comment: Yeah my problem is that the first array is Categories, and the second one is Dish when i do a foreach($dishes as $dish) it says the index is not right.. because I only want to iterate the Dish Array but i think it tries to find $dish['Dish']['dish_name'] but first there is a $dish['DishCategory]['somethingelsehere'] i do not want to include the dishcategory and I am not sure how to except that.. sorry.. its been a little confusing moving to cakephp thank you

Comment: Did not figure it out but i am giving you the answer thank you